# Node.js - Pausing script execution in another thread

Tags: javascript, node.js

.:Disclaimer:.

Please note that I am trying to achieve something with node.js which might go against its design principles. However as node.js goes against the norm of "javascript is for client side", I am also trying something different here. Please bear with me.

.:Background:.

I have a requirement where Java Scripts need to be narrative (read from beginning to end) for simplistic scripts for simplistic users. I will also offer an Async scripting ability for more advanced users.

I understand the event driven methodology of node.js, and have a solution working based on Async callbacks. Now I am trying to simplify this for our more basic scripting requirements.

.:The Question:.

Is there a way to run a script (using its own sandbox) where execution can be paused while a result is being delivered.

E.g.

```
var util = require('util'),
vm = require('vm'),
user = require('user');

vm.runInThisContext('user.WaitForProceed(); console.log('Waiting over');');

console.log('Finished!');
```

User is my own module that will do the waiting. Basically I want it to sit there and block on that line in the vm object until it has received a result back. After which it will continue onto the console.log line.

The output of this example unimportant as it is also achievable through callbacks. The narrative nature of the example script is more important for this solution.

- J

Comment: So who proclaimed this so called NORM(!?) "javascript is for client side" - or is it that you (and others) only ever saw it there and declared the only thing YOU/THEY knew must therefore be a "norm"? Anyway, no there is no way to pause. The JS machine continues to run the event loop and only stops if there is nothing to be run. So the only way to stop is to have no more code and no more events (with an event listener attached). The only thing you can do is wait for that"proceed" event.

Comment: ...so you have to have an event to listen to, fired by your "user" object. But you said you already have such a solution, so the important thing for you to take away from this is how the JS engine itself actually works, then you'll get a better feeling for this stuff :)  You should tell us more about what user.WaitForProcceed() does ;)

Comment: "...so the important thing for you to take away from this is how the JS engine itself actually works..." Norm is how others tell me things "should work". I understand the limitations and functionality of node, however as with all developers I deal with people that don't. They however want to use this system, in their way. I simply explore what is possible.

Comment: Think of "user.WaitForProceed();" as a blocker, it stops the code from running any future until asked to wake up again. Like @jp-richardson example this would block the main message loop. It is this that I am looking to avoid.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to pause the execution in Node. At least they tell us so :)

There are some libraries which support an advanced flow control, like [Invoke](https://github.com/repeatingbeats/invoke), maybe this could help, but I understands, that's not what you asked for :)

Also you could implement a busy-loop using [nextTick()](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/process.html#process.nextTick)

Or you could implement a blocking call in C(++) and provide it as a library. I never did this.

One last way is to [readFileSync()](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.readFileSync) to a namedpipe which closes on a certian event.

As you already mentioned, it's against the language principes, therefor these solutions are all hacky.

Comment: There is. Using native Node.js addons... see my answer.

Comment: Excellent little hack, very effective. I couldn't get a named pipe on Windows so I used an ordinary file and arranged to have the string "EOF" written to it when I wanted to resume execution, then continually called readSync until the string appeared. Don't judge me.

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to sleep the execution of the Node process, you can. However, as you state, it seems that you're fully aware of the implications.

Here is an NPM module to do this: 
https://github.com/ErikDubbelboer/node-sleep

You can use it like so:

```
var sleep = require('sleep');
sleep.sleep(1); //sleep for 1 sec
sleep.usleep(2000000); //sleep for 2 sec
```

I partially write this for ***future visitors that arrive by Google search***: **You should not use the aforementioned technique.** If you decide that you must, be aware that this will block your Node process and it won't be able to do any additional work until the sleep period is over. Additionally, you will violate every expectation of any user who is aware that it's Node.js programs, as Node.js programs are suppose to be non-blocking.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if this still pauses the main message loop if you fork a vm off. The issue still is I will require something else to wake up the forked off process. Maybe fibers (mentioned below) will have a good result.

Comment: Um, Erik Dubbelboer's sleep module really really sucks on windows. Its pretty unacceptable.

Comment: 1) He didn't say that he needed a solution to Windows. 2) This was posted over a year ago. 3) Most importantly, trying to suspend the Node.js execution thread is, in almost all cases, a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you realy want to pause execution while waiting for result you may try to work with [node-sync](https://github.com/0ctave/node-sync). It build on [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers). Your application needs to be executed with node-fibers script instead of node. node-sync adds sync method to Function.prototype that allows to run it syncroniously.

Also you need to wrap your call in the fiber (thread) so as not to block the event-loop.

```js
var Sync = require('sync');

var someAsyncFunction = function(a, b, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var result = a + b;
        callback(undefined, result);
    }, 1000);
};

// Run in a fiber
Sync(function(){
    // This code runs in separate fiber and does not block the event loop

    // First argument is 'this' context
    var result = someAsyncFunction.sync(null, 2, 3);
    // Waiting one second
    console.log(result); // Will output 5
});

// Event loop here
```

Please be careful with it. You need to understand that is not the node way.

Comment: Very nice. Sadly I need the main script to stop execution at the sync function call, and then at a later date be asked to start again. This will work well for other things I need to achieve. Maybe I can use this as the runner of a vm and pause that fiber. I will have a play.

Comment: If you need to stop execution the main event loop while function work, just remove Sync(function(){ }); wrapper from example. This should pause the main event loop.